# std::map insert stuck in infinite loop or gives access violation error

Tags: c++, access-violation, stdmap

I have declared a std::map in .h file

```
#include "pl.h"
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class ReadingXDSLfile
{
public:

     ReadingXDSLfile();
     ~ReadingXDSLfile();
     void readDotXDSLFile(string fileName, ifstream &file);
     void writeNodesList();


protected:
    typedef std::map<std::string, int> nodesMap;

    nodesMap nodes;

    std::vector<string> nodesName;
    std::map<std::string, int>::iterator nodeItr, nodeItr1;
    string outFileName;
private:
};
```

and in .cpp file when i try to insert an item using following line of code then it gives access violation error

```
int counter=0;
string strNode;
...
....
....
std::pair<string, int>prNode (strNode, counter);
     nodes.insert(prNode);
```

error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x0043c5d9 in testMMHC.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000002c.
```

Now i declared a temp map variable in the function (.cpp file), it allows me to insert. But when i copy temp map to the global map declared in the header file then it goes in infinite loop and never exit.

It happens with all map variables declared in header file.

Comment: Please provide some details about how you define and use `strNode` and `counter` before that line. Even better, please provide the full source code.

Comment: I agree. Have you tried something like `nodes.insert(pair<std::string, int>("Hello", 5));` to debug and test if the map is working?

Comment: Yes it also gives me the same error. If i use `nodes.clear();` before starting insertion then it stuck in infinite loop.

Comment: You shouldn't declare variable in .h file: `std::map<std::string, int> nodes;` Add extern `extern std::map<std::string, int> nodes;` and define it in .cpp file: `std::map<std::string, int> nodes;`

Comment: @PiotrNycz Thank you but how i can use `extern` keyword. when i use `extern std::map<std::string, int> nodes;` in a .cpp file then it gives me compilation error `error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class std::map<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,int,struct std::less<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,....`

Comment: use extern in header only. Not use it in .cpp file. And I am not sure this is your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, declaring a typedef for your map in your header is fine, but don't declare the variable itself unless you use `extern`. There should be only one, and it should be in your .cpp file.

In .h file:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

typedef std::map<std::string, int> NodeMap;
extern NodeMap nodes;
```

Next, your .cpp file:

```
NodeMap nodes;
```

And lastly, regarding insertion, you have a plethora of possible ways to do it.

```
std::string strIndex = "foo";
int value = 0

// one way.
nodes[strIndex] = value;

// another way
nodes.insert(NodeMap::value_type(strIndex,value));
```

to show a few examples.

**EDIT:** The OP has changed the source content of the question and now shows that `nodes` is not a global, but rather is a member variable of another class. Everything about `extern` in this answer just became moot.

The offset of the violation indicates that one of the iterators or the class itself is being referenced through a null pointer. 0x2C is 44-bytes deep off NULL, whiuch indicates to me that the `ReadingXDSLfile` ***object*** being referenced is likely coming from a NULL pointer.

Without more information from the OP about how the referenced object is being allocated and accessed, I'm afaid I can't offer up much more than a well-defined tutorial on how to extern a variable in a header, which should be evident has nothing to do with this problem.

Comment: The method that he used to insert should be fine as well. For `std::map`, `value_type` is `typedef`ed to `pair<Key, T>`.

Comment: Agreed, but the function *signature* calls for value_type, i.e.: `pair<iterator,bool> insert ( const value_type& x )` or at least my spec says so. that is why I always use it.

Comment: Yeah, but after compilation, there is no difference. See the example code here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/insert/ Regardless, `value_type` is a little cleaner to read. But I usually use `pair<Key, T>` because it's what I'm used to.

Comment: When i use `extern` keyword in header file then it gives me compilation error `error C2071: 'plBayesianNetworkFromXDSLfile::nodes' : illegal storage class`

Comment: @Geoff_Montee There is one *major* difference. Using pair<> implies you *know* they're the same. Nowhere I'm aware is it specified they *have* to be. Thus I always use what the signature calls for. if they're the same, so be it. But when/if I'm ever using an STL where they're not, it will still compile. Using pair will no longer. Been bitten too many times on things like that. Its just a discipline thing for me.

Comment: @user986789 update the code in your question with your header file declaration. It appears you're not showing us something.

Comment: True. I've always assumed that cplusplus.com is an authoritative source. Someone over there probably has a copy of the C++ spec. I've never read it to be 100% sure.

Comment: @user986789 Your updated source completely changes the context of the quesiton, as now it shows that `nodes` is actually a member variable, and not declared global. Thus everything you've seen about `extern` etc. just became irrelevant.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thank you now it works, just we have to use `typedef std::map<std::string, int> NodeMap;
extern NodeMap nodes;` statement before the class declaration in header file and the same in cpp file.

Comment: @user986789 I'm completely stymied as to how it could work with what *I* know about your code (i.e. what is presented here), but you're closer to the code than I at this point, so if it works for you, thats all that matters. glad it helped.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thank you again for your help. Now i identified the exact problem. There was an error in object declaration as you mentioned in your post NULL pointer `ReadingXDSLfile * XDSLobject;` In this case extern is work.